# recycler view gridmanager layout column spacing does not give equal space in all side

Tags: android, xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKj4j.png)//I have recycler view as follows in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/grid_recycle_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:background="#f8f9fb"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_recycle_view"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

//in my onprepareGridView method i have done following

```
private void prepareGridRecycleView() {
        gridRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        SpaceItemDecoration itemDecoration = new SpaceItemDecoration(10);
        gridRecyclerView.setClipToPadding(false);
        gridRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
        adapter = new ShopPageGridViewAdapter(ShopPageContent.this, new ShopPageHeaderGridInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(boolean isClicked) {
                gridRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                listRecycleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, new ShopPageHeaderListInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(boolean isClicked) {

            }
        }, new CartCoordivateInfoHolder() {
            @Override
            public void setViewCoordinate(ImageView view, int x, int y) {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.bringToFront();
                view.invalidate();
                int pos[] = new int[2];
                cart.getLocationOnScreen(pos);
                Log.e("x", String.valueOf(pos[0]));
                Log.e("y", String.valueOf(pos[1]));
                TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, pos[0] - x, 0, pos[1] - y);
                anim.setDuration(5000);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                view.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        });
        final GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return adapter.isPositionHeader(position) ? manager.getSpanCount() : 1;
            }
        });
        gridRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    }
```

//and the item decorator class looks like the following

```
public class SpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int space;

    public SpaceItemDecoration(int space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                               RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        if (position == 0) {
            outRect.left = 0;
            outRect.right = 0;
            outRect.bottom = 0;
            outRect.top = 0;
            return;
        }
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 1 || parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 2) {
            outRect.top = 0;
            outRect.left =(space);
            outRect.right = space;
            outRect.bottom = space;
            return;
        }
        outRect.left = space;[enter image description here][1]
        outRect.right = space;
        outRect.bottom = space;
        outRect.top = space;
    }
}
```

//The problem i am facing is  space at the left side and right side different. Left side space are smaller than the right side space.

//image link

Comment: i have added image link here
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/cKj4j.png

Comment: Change your `SpaceItemDecoration `.

Comment: what is the problem in above decoration . Please give me some hint so that i can change with some bit of understanding

Comment: If you have an 2 column grid. On the fist column set margin on all sides and  on the second skip, eg. left margin.

Comment: ok i understand what you mean but how can i get the position of element in recyclerview item decorator class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to:

```
public class SpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int space;

    public SpaceItemDecoration(int space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                               RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

        outRect.left = space;
        outRect.right = space;
        outRect.bottom = space;
        outRect.top = space;

        if(position%2==0){
          outRect.left = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

This code is not tested;